# Issue when retrieving an NSInteger from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, nsinteger

I'm experiencing an issue when saving & retrieving an int from NSUserDefaults. I am saving to NSUserDefaults using the following code:

```
int globalRank = 1;
NSUserDefaults *submissionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[submissionDefaults setInteger: globalRank forKey:@"globalRankIntForLT"];
NSLog(@"updating %@ as the globalRank in NSUserDefaults",globalRank);
[submissionDefaults synchronize];
```

This appears to work correctly. In my output I can see:

```
"updating 1 as the globalRank in NSUserDefaults"
```

When I retreive the number using the code below:

```
NSUserDefaults *submissionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger *currentGlobalRank = [submissionDefaults integerForKey:@"globalRankIntForLT"];
int currentGlobalRankInt = currentGlobalRank;
NSLog(@"Retrieved skip int is: %d as nsinteger is: %d",currentGlobalRankInt, currentGlobalRank);

I get output:
"Retrieved skip int is: 4978484032 as nsinteger is: 4978484032"
```

I later pass this int to another method that returns an error because 4978484032 is bigger than it was expecting.

NSUserDefaults contains an NSInteger but it is coming incorrectly even at that point. What am I doing wrong? Thanks, James

Answer (score 1):

`NSInteger` is a primitive type, not an object. It should be `NSInteger currentGlobalRank` instead of `NSInteger *currentGlobalRank`.
You can use `NSInteger` instead of `int` in your code. There's no need to convert an `NSInteger` to `int`.

On iOS, `NSInteger` is defined as `int`, on OS X it's `long`.

Comment: I didn't know NSInteger was primitive. I will try this tonight & update results. Thanks, James

Comment: @JamesLCQ "I didn't know" - **you should always read the documentation of types and classes you want to use. Don't guess.**

Comment: I did read the documentation but it must have slipped my mind. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting an integer and trying to retrieve a POINTER to integer. Change:

```
NSInteger *currentGlobalRank = [submissionDefaults integerForKey:@"globalRankIntForLT"];
```

to:

```
NSInteger currentGlobalRank = [submissionDefaults integerForKey:@"globalRankIntForLT"];
```

Despite `NSInteger` starts from NS that's not a subclass of `NSObject`, it's just primitive

Comment: I didn't know NSInteger was primitive. I will try this tonight & update results. Thanks, James

Answer (score 0):

Change this code...

```
NSInteger *currentGlobalRank = [submissionDefaults integerForKey:@"globalRankIntForLT"];
int currentGlobalRankInt = currentGlobalRank;
NSLog(@"Retrieved skip int is: %d as nsinteger is: %d",currentGlobalRankInt, currentGlobalRank);
```

to...

```
NSInteger *currentGlobalRank = [submissionDefaults integerForKey:@"globalRankIntForLT"];
int currentGlobalRankInt = [currentGlobalRank intValue];
NSLog(@"Retrieved skip int is: %d as nsinteger is: %@",currentGlobalRankInt, currentGlobalRank);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSInteger` or a wrapper class like  `NSNumber` instead of `int`.

And you are putting a ***** by mistake... in **NSInteger *currentGlobalRank**

```
NSInteger globalRank = 1;
NSUserDefaults *submissionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[submissionDefaults setInteger: globalRank forKey:@"globalRankIntForLT"];
NSLog(@"updating %@ as the globalRank in NSUserDefaults",globalRank);
[submissionDefaults synchronize];



NSUserDefaults *submissionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger currentGlobalRank = [submissionDefaults integerForKey:@"globalRankIntForLT"];
NSLog(@"Retrieved skip int is: %d as nsinteger is: %d",currentGlobalRank, currentGlobalRank);
```

Comment: NSInteger isn't a wrapper class, it's defined as int. (Depends on the platform you're compiling for.)